# str_replace doesn't replace newlines gotten from form's textarea

Tags: php, xhtml, newline, str-replace

I have a text area written in html.
I want to get its text with PHP, but I want to replace newlines with < br / > tags.
Then the resulting string is written into a text file.

```
$puhdas['arvostelu'] = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n", "\r"), '<br />', strip_tags($_POST['arvostelu']));
```

Why that doesn't replace them? I can still see newlines breaking the text apart in the txt file PHP creates.

Comment: can you add `var_dump(strip_tags($_POST['arvostelu']))` like to see the output

Comment: I found the problem, I was using wrong variable name ($_POST instead of $puhdas) in the fwrite function. I assume questions cannot be deleted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP already has [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

```
$puhdas['arvostelu'] = nl2br(strip_tags($_POST['arvostelu']));
```

Please note that they might also as well be `\t` instead of `\n`

Comment: Unfortunately, using nl2br does not solve this.
vardump shows it as it should be, but the txt file I write it, shows the the line breaking.

Comment: I asked you for the var_dump output but you did not send it .. how am i suppose to know what you are dealing with .... add the var dump to pastebin .. so that i can review